# "Must be owner of table A", but A doesnt exist

Tags: django, postgresql

I`m trying to run database migrations, but getting the following error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: must be owner of table request_settings
```

This is from my .env file:

```
...
DB_USER=idaproject
DB_NAME=wellton
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
...
```

So, I assume, this table should be inside "wellton" database. The user "idaproject" is the owner of "wellton" database and has all priveleges and rights on the database.
Then I tried to change owner of request_settings table with

```
ALTER TABLE request_settings OWNER TO idaproject;
```

But seems like it doesn't exist

```
ERROR:  relation "request_settings" does not exist
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Presumably you are missing the schema.

Comment: I do have a schema "public"

Comment: And, is the table in that schema?

Comment: Well it should be, but you can see from the log that it "doesnt exist"

Comment: If you look in the wrong place and don't find it, that's what you get. For example: `/* nothing on the serach path */ SET search_path = ''; SELECT * FROM atable;`.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot)  That's right, I was not connected to my database, so that's why the search hadn't showed me the specific table.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so the problem was exactly as the log says (surprisingly): I just had to change the owner of the table. The reason that the table hadn't been found when I tried to change the owner was that I just handn't been connected to the database "wellton".

So I did this in a psql console:

```
\c wellton
ALTER TABLE request_settings OWNER TO idaproject;
```

and it worked.